# Help me fix my JavaScript quiz

Tags: javascript

I have been at this quiz for ages now and just can't get it to work on my webpage. What is the error?

The HTML:

```
<body>
    <div id="content1">
       <div class="position">
           <div class="form">

              <h3>Quiz</h3>
              <form name="myForm">
                  Question 1: Which of these is a letter?<br>
                  <input type="radio" name="q1" value="correct">A<br>
                  <input type="radio" name="q1">1<br>
                  <input type="radio" name="q1">#<br>
                  <input type="radio" name="q1">None of the Above<br>
                  <br>

                  Question 2: Which of these is a number?<br>
                  <input type="radio" name="q2">A<br>
                  <input type="radio" name="q2" value="correct">1<br>
                  <input type="radio" name="q2">#<br>
                  <input type="radio" name="q2">None of the Above<br>
                  <br>

                  etc...

                  <input name="button" type="Submit" onClick="onclick=return checkAnswers()" />
              </form>
         </div>
      </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

The JavaScript code:

```
<head>
    <script language="JavaScript">
        //Put all the question sets into this array.
         var allQuestions = new Array(document.myForm.q1,
                               document.myForm.q2,
                               document.myForm.q3,
                               document.myForm.q4);

        //Redirects if 75% or greater, returns false otherwise.
        function checkAnswers(){
            var totalScore = 0; //initialize to 0

            //Go through each question set.
            for (var i in allQuestions) {
                var temp = allQuestions[i];

                //Go through each radio button in the current question set.
                for (var j = 0; j < temp.length; j++) {

                    //If the correct one is chosen then add 1 to total score.
                    if (temp[j].value == "correct" && temp[j].checked == true) {
                        totalScore++;
                    }
                }
            }

            //If the total percentage is more than 75%.
            if ((totalScore/allQuestions.length) >= .75) {
                //Alert and move on.
                alert("Congratulations! Your score of " + totalScore +
                     " out of " + allQuestions.length + " is good enough to proceed!");
            else{
                //Otherwise alert and return false.
                alert("You must get at least 75% correct to move on!");
                return false;
            }
        }
    </script>
</head>
```

Comment: Just a thought, but depending on what you're trying to accomplish, you might want to move some or all of this computation to server side logic. As it is, anyone who views your source code can see the correct answers.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You access the form elements before they exist
You missed a curly bracket before the else. I eliminated it.

```
<script type="text/javascript>
function validate(theForm) {
 //put all the question sets into this array
  var allQuestions = new Array(theForm.q1,
                        theForm.q2 /*,
                        theForm.q3,
                        theForm.q4 */);

  return checkAnswers(allQuestions);
}
 //redirects if 75% or greater, returns false otherwise
function checkAnswers(allQuestions){
  var totalScore = 0; //initialize to 0
  //go through each question set
  for (var i in allQuestions) {
    var temp = allQuestions[i];
  //go through each radio button in the current question set
    for (var j = 0; j < temp.length; j++) {

    //if the correct one is chosen then add 1 to total score
      if (temp[j].value == "correct" && temp[j].checked == true) {
        totalScore++;
      }
    }
  }

  //if the total percentage is more than 75%
  if ((totalScore/allQuestions.length) >= .75) {
  //alert and move on
    alert("Congratulations! Your score of " + totalScore +
     " out of " + allQuestions.length + " is good enough to proceed!");
     return true; // this will submit the form. return false if you do not want to submit at all
  }
  //otherwise alert and return false
  alert("You must get at least 75% correct to move on!");
  return false;
}
</script>



 <h3>Wine Quiz</h3>
        <form name="Quiz" onsubmit="return validate(this)">

.
.
<input type="submit" />
</form>
```

Comment: @mplungjan: You don't _need_ a dot, you just have extra whitespace between the end of your second point and the code.

Comment: @mplungjan: I think I figured it out; the bullet parser keeps going, despite a code block following it. Putting almost anything after the bullet with spacing (e.g. <bullets><blank line><text not starting with bullet character><blank line><code block>) signals the parser to stop and the code block will pick up. Also, some of your code is prefixed with a TAB instead of 4 spaces, may have something to do with formatting. Either way, good catch.

Comment: Great, thanks. 
Removing the list fixed the code representation after I also removed tabs]

Comment: Moses - good point - its only for a simple project tho. I read the answers above but still can't get this thing to work??

Comment: The live version is here if anyone can still help me?   http://bit.ly/hR8JYk

Comment: This is VERY wrong: 
`onClick="onclick=return checkAnswers()"` instead use `<form name="myForm" onsubmit="return validate(this)">` as I suggested

Comment: Please see my edits. You had HTML in the script instead of replacing your HTML tags with mine. Apologies for not clearly showing you where the script stopped and the html started. I had issues with SO's formatting since I started my answer with a list. It has now been fixed

Comment: mplungjan - sincere thanks for your help on this. It works perfectly now :-)

Comment: :) You are welcome. Happy New Year

Answer (score 0):

This is the working solution and comments for anyone who is looking for it!

```
// JavaScript Document

function validate(theForm) {  

//put the questions into  an array  
  var allQuestions = new Array(theForm.q1,  
                              theForm.q2,  
                              theForm.q3,  
                              theForm.q4);  

  return checkAnswers(allQuestions);  
}

 //checks all answers  
function checkAnswers(allQuestions){  
  var totalScore = 0; //initialize to 0 

  //go through each question set  
  for (var i in allQuestions) {  
    var temp = allQuestions[i];  

  //go through each radio button in the current question set  
    for (var j = 0; j < temp.length; j++) {  

    //if the correct one is chosen then add 1 to total score  
      if (temp[j].value == "correct" && temp[j].checked == true) {  
        totalScore++;  
      }  
    }  
  }  

  //if the total percentage is more than 75%  
  if ((totalScore/allQuestions.length) >= .75) {  

  //alert and move on  
    alert("Congratulations! Your score of " + totalScore +  
     " out of " + allQuestions.length + " is very good!");  
     return true;  
  }  

    //otherwise alert and return false  
    alert("You must get at least 75% correct to pass");  
    return false;  
}
```