# Help needed with simple js quiz form!

Tags: javascript

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Help me fix my JavaScript Quiz](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4556097/help-me-fix-my-javascript-quiz)

Hi, this javascript form isn't working as there is some kind of bug/error in the code which I can't find! It should activate a pop-up after answering the 4 questions and clicking the 'submit' button - letting the user know if they have passed or failed the little test.

Instead of posting all the code it is here in the doc. head here: http://bit.ly/g4jO3J

Any help would be appreciated for this project.

Comment: I have a feeling I've seen this exact question some hours ago...wait a minute! http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4556097/help-me-fix-my-javascript-quiz-closed

Comment: How is this question different than your [last closed question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4556097/help-me-fix-my-javascript-quiz-closed)?

Comment: I posted again because someone closed my last question on me before I got a working solution! It's now working and life is good again :-)

Answer (score 0):

You have a redundant `onclick=` in your submit button. Instead of:

```
<input name="button" type="Submit" onClick="onclick=return checkAnswers()" />
```

Use:

```
<input name="button" type="Submit" onClick="return checkAnswers()" />
```

Comment: Thanks - have the changed code as suggested, but still not working for some reason?

Comment: Thanks for your help  - I got it working eventually!!

Answer (score 0):

Your script contains HTML:

```
<script>
// your code

<form name="Quiz" onsubmit="return validate(this)">
<input type="submit" />
</form>

</script>
```

That causes a syntax error. But that's probably not the problem.

Comment: Thanks - have removed the html. Still can't figure out problem...

Answer (score 0):

1. `function validate(myForm) {` => `function validate() {`
2. `var allQuestions = new Array(Quiz.q1,Quiz.q2,Quiz.q3,Quiz.q4);` =>  `var allQuestions = new Array(document.Quiz.q1,document.Quiz.q2,document.Quiz.q3,document.Quiz.q4);`
3. `onClick="return checkAnswers()"` => `onClick="return validate()"`

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your help  - I got it working eventually!!

If anyone is looking for a simple javascript quiz then visit the page (link above) and click view source to see the code.